# Removing Punctuation From Python List Items

Tags: python, list

I have a list like

```
['hello', '...', 'h3.a', 'ds4,']
```

this should turn into

```
['hello', 'h3a', 'ds4']
```

and i want to remove only the punctuation leaving the letters and numbers intact.
Punctuation is anything in the `string.punctuation` constant.
I know that this is gunna be simple but im kinda noobie at python so...

Thanks,
giodamelio

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming that your initial list is stored in a variable x, you can use this:

```
>>> x = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in x]
>>> print(x)
['hello', '', 'h3a', 'ds4']
```

To remove the empty strings:

```
>>> x = [s for s in x if s]
>>> print(x)
['hello', 'h3a', 'ds4']
```

Answer (score 9):

Use string.translate:

```
>>> import string
>>> test_case = ['hello', '...', 'h3.a', 'ds4,']
>>> [s.translate(None, string.punctuation) for s in test_case]
['hello', '', 'h3a', 'ds4']
```

For the documentation of translate, see http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

Comment: +1 cause i like it and didn't know translate can delete chars without the weird translation table.

Answer (score 3):

In python 3+ use this instead:

```
import string
s = s.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import string

print ''.join((x for x in st if x not in string.punctuation))
```

ps st is the string. for the list is the same...

```
[''.join(x for x in par if x not in string.punctuation) for par in alist]
```

i think works well. look at string.punctuaction:

```
>>> print string.punctuation
!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a new list:

```
[re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', x) for x in list_of_strings]
```

Comment: That won't do anything to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that string.punctuation works in English, but may not work for other languages with other punctuation marks.

You could add them to a list LIST_OF_LANGUAGE_SPECIFIC_PUNCTUATION and then concatenate it to string.punctuation to get a fuller set of punctuation.

```
punctuation =  string.punctuation + [LIST_OF_LANGUAGE_SPECIFIC_PUNCTUATION]
```

Comment: you should have written it in a simple comment as this is not a full answer.