# Strip Specific Punctuation in Python 2.x

Tags: python, string, strip

I'm using Python v2.6 and I have a string which contains a number of punctuation characters I'd like to strip out. Now I've looked at using the `string.punctuation()` function but unfortunately, I want to strip out all punctuation characters except fullstops and dashes. In total, there are only a total of 5 punctuation marks I'd like to strip out - `()\"'`

Any suggestions? I'd like this to be the most efficient way.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371231/removing-punctuation-from-python-list-items/4371351#4371351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.translate(table[, deletechars])`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) with `table` set to `None`, which will result in all characters from `deletechars` being removed from the string:

```
s.translate(None, r"()\"'")
```

Some examples:

```
>>> "\"hello\" '(world)'".translate(None, r"()\"'")
'hello world'
>>> "a'b c\"d e(f g)h i\\j".translate(None, r"()\"'")
'ab cd ef gh ij'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [string.translate](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate):

```
s = ''' abc(de)f\gh"i' '''
print(s.translate(None, r"()\"'"))
 # abcdefghi
```

or [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
re.sub(r"[\\()'\"]",'',s)
```

but `string.translate` appears to be an order of magnitude faster:

```
In [148]: %timeit (s*1000).translate(None, r"()\"'")
10000 loops, best of 3: 112 us per loop

In [146]: %timeit re.sub(r"[\\()'\"]",'',s*1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.11 ms per loop
```

Comment: No need to make a blank translation table; just use `None`.

Comment: Also, your code formatting is broken. Looks like an unmatched `"`.

Comment: Josh, thanks for the correction regarding `translate(None,...)`.  Where is the formatting incorrect? I've run the code. It seems to work.

Comment: well, `print` shows up in red. Looks like SO isn't parsing the triple quotes correctly. Maybe you need to hint to it that the code snippet is Python? I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile("[\(\)\\\\'\"]")
>>> r.sub("", "\"hello\" '(world)'\\\\\\")
'hello world'
```

Comment: This doesn't remove backslashes from the original string.  `r.sub('', 'a\\b') --> 'a\\b'`

Comment: Right, there are a lot of answers on this one, but I think a compiled regexp would be the most *efficient* solution. And always remember, “Give a man a regular expression and he’ll match a string… but by teaching him how to create them, you’ve given him enough rope to hang himself”

Comment: @Paulo: I don't like raw strings, they remind me of paths in Windows ;)

Comment: @Paulo: I find that it depends on how much backslashes you need. `r"C:\Program Files\SomeCompany\SomeProgram Version 7\Internals\foobar.bla"` is obviously much nicer than the alternative, but a lot of times I need `"\t\n\0\xad\xde\xef\xbe"`, too...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6710/discussion-between-cha0site-and-paulo-scardine)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of all the characters you don't want:

```
unwanted = ['(', ')', '\\', '"', '\'']
```

Then you could make a function `strip_punctuation(s)` like so:

```
def strip_punctuation(s): 
    for u in unwanted: 
        s = s.replace(u, '')
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict of all the characters you want to be replaced and replace them with char of your choice.

```
char_replace = {"'":"" , "(":"" , ")":"" , "\":"" , """:""}

for i,j in char_replace.iteritems():
        string = string.replace(i,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = r'''\(""Hello ''W\orld)'''
strip_chars = r'''()\'"'''
```

using comprehension:

```
''.join(x for x in my_string if x not in strip_chars)
```

using filter:

```
''.join(filter(lambda x: x not in strip_chars, my_string))
```

output:

```
Hello World
```