# Python - Removing punctuation from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to remove the punc from a text file.

The text file is like this

> ffff, hhhh, & tommorw home,
>   Have you from gone?

I am trying

> punc=(",./;'?&-")
>
> f = open('file.txt', 'r')
>
> ```
> for line in f:
>     strp=line.replace(punc,"")
>     print(strp)
> ```

I need the output to be:

> ffff hhhh  tommorw home
>
> ```
> Have you from gone
> ```

This is returning each line, but the punc is still there> could use some help. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Do you want **all** punctuation stripped, regardless of where it appears, or only at word boundaries?

Comment: i need all gone anywhere in the text file

Comment: related: [Remove punctation from Unicode formatted strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11066400/4279)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Punctuation From Python List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371231/removing-punctuation-from-python-list-items)

Answer (score 9):

Use `str.translate` to delete characters from a string.

In Python 2.x:

```
# first arg is translation table, second arg is characters to delete
strp = line.translate(None, punc)
```

In Python 3:

```
# translation table maps code points to replacements, or None to delete
transtable = {ord(c): None for c in punc}
strp = line.translate(transtable)
```

Alternately, you can use `str.maketrans` to build `transtable`:

```
# first and second arg are matching translated values, third arg (optional) is the characters to delete
transtable = str.maketrans('', '', punc)
strp = line.translate(transtable)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import string
>>> with open('/tmp/spam.txt') as f:
...   for line in f:
...     words = [x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in line.split()]
...     print ' '.join(w for w in words if w)
... 
ffff hhhh tommorw home
Have you from gone
```

Comment: That is an oddly complicated way of solving this problem. Why are you only removing punctuation at the start and end of segments (x.strip())?

Comment: That's how I understood the problem, I didn't want for example hyphenated words or words with apostrophes to be mangled.

Comment: Oh. I would have expected the OP wants the hyphens stripped from them as well, but it's not clear for the question now that I look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

str_link = open('replace.txt','r').read()

#str_link = "ffff, hhhh, & tommorow home, Have you from gone?"

punc = list(",./;'?&-")

for line in str_link:
    if line in punc:
        str_link = str_link.replace(line,"") 

print str_link
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea of using `str.translate` is great, but here's one other way to do it:

```
punc=set(",./;'?&-")

for line in f:
    strp=''.join(c for c in line if not c in punc)
    print(strp)
```