# Removing punctuation from only the beginning and end of each element in a list in python

Tags: python, list, punctuation

I'm fairly new to python (and this community), this is a question branching off of a question asked and answered from a long time ago from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371231/removing-punctuation-from-python-list-items)

With a list like:

```
['hello', '...', 'h3.a', 'ds4,']
```

Creating a new list x with no punctuation (and deleting empty elements) would be:

```
x = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in x]
x = [s for s in x if s]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'h3a', 'ds4']
```

However, how would I be able to remove all punctuation only from the beginning and end of each element? I mean, to instead output this:

```
['hello', 'h3.a', 'ds4']
```

In this case, keeping the period in the h3a but removing the comma at the end of the ds4.

Comment: `s.strip(string.punctuation)` would be a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regular expressions. `re.sub()` can replace all matches of a regex with a string.

```
import re
X = ['hello', '.abcd.efg.', 'h3.a', 'ds4,']
X_rep = [re.sub(r"(^[^\w]+)|([^\w]+$)", "", x) for x in X] 
print(X_rep)
# Output: ['hello', 'abcd.efg', 'h3.a', 'ds4']
```

Explanation of regex: [Try it](https://regex101.com/r/KWH2J3/2)

- `(^[^\w]+)`:

  - `^`: Beginning of string
  - `[^\w]+`: One or more non-word characters
- `|`: The previous expression, or the next expression
- `([^\w]+$)`:

  - `[^\w]+`: One or more non-word characters
  - `$`: End of string

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['hello', '...', 'h3.a', 'ds4,']
x[0] = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in x][0]
x[(len(x)-1)] = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in x][(len(x)-1)]
x = [s for s in x if s]
print(x)
```

Comment: Please see [this](/help/formatting) for formatting help. Please also take the [tour] and read [answer]. While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_ Welcome to Stack Overflow!